# Dynamically bind the data-bind attribute in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

I want to bind the data-bind attribute dynamically.

Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/km89jfyp/5/

```
/km89jfyp/5/
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @ACOMIT001 I want to added data-bind="numeric:MachineNo for some columns and data-bind="text:CountLabel". I need to round of some values in table body.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the case of <td data-bind="numeric: MachineNo">? numeric isn't a built-in binding and even if it was I'm not sure what it would do when attached to a TD element.

Comment: Do you want to display the DataType property of your viewModel in the content of the TD? If so, use the data-bind="text: ...". For formatting the machine number in a special number format, have a look at knockout filters or write your custom "numeric" directive

Comment: @JasonSpake If it is Numeric then i am validating the text either by Integer or decimal. For Example Machine can be only number(1,2,3,etc) but if you take average of RPM then it will be of decimals(2360.6869), In this case i will be fixing the decimal to 2 places 2360.69. Hope you got what i am trying to say.

Comment: @cmonsqpr I don't want to display the datatype to end user but i need to manipulate things on that. I will be doing some custom validation like round off, fixed to decimal, remove the unwanted  character.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I know what you want to achieve, but it seems you want to use a different KO directive depending on the value of your DataType observable? And you wondered if you can dynamically select a directive that has the same name as the value of your DataType observable? I don't know of a way to do that, other than adding several ko: if DataType()=='numeric' and then embedd an element with the actual (custom?) directive ko: myCustomNumericDirective: value

Comment: Sorry for the mess . I will show the sample how i need it . For Example in table tbody the tabledata has 123.6787 , for this i need to show as 123.68.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the extra information from these comments. As it stands the question doesn't say much and isn't a very good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` takes the name of a binding to apply as a string so you can use that to dynamically apply a binding. You can use it from your javascript in an event, or you can make a custom binding to use it inside your html. A custom binding might look something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.applyBinding = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, bindingContext) {
    var bindingName = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); 
    var target = ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor().bindingTarget);
    if (bindingName) {
      var binding = {};
      binding[bindingName] = function() {
        return target;
      };

      ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, binding, bindingContext);
    }
  }
}
```

You would use it in a binding like: `<span data-bind="applyBinding: MyBinding, bindingTarget: myValue"></span>`

Your code still leaves me with a lot of questions so I can't be sure this will work for you. The sample you linked has a lot of issues besides just the binding so I had to make some assumptions to fix errors and get it working, but here's an example based on your code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/swvo7u00/)

Comment: ,I haven't shared entire code and logic here.I am binding the table header and table body dynamically based on the user selection field columns. i will be binding the row and body  based on what the end user have selected. For example if the end user selects the text column(Name.Addr,etc) then he selects numeric column(age,zip code,phone etc),then decimal field (salary and some other decimal field).And also i will be showing whether he is active,Inactive as icon. So i want to archive similarly thing in Knockout. So how can i set the data-bind="text:/Numeric/numerictext" dynamically

Comment: Yes. Was my answer helpful then or did you have problems adapting it to your code?

Comment: #jason,It didn't solve my issue. check this link https://jsfiddle.net/swvo7u00/3/

Comment: @Avi You're trying to apply a numeric binding to a text value so yeah that's not going to work. What did you expect to happen in a numeric column with the value "tester"?

Comment: I will be having both text as well as numeric binding. How to do that dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Updated the logic to include both numeric and text.
https://jsfiddle.net/swvo7u00/4/

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    //element -> value
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var target = valueAccessor();
        var newValue = $(element).val();
        if (ko.isObservable(target)) { target(newValue); } else { target = newValue; }
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, bindingContext) {
    //model -> element
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    if (typeof value === "number")
    {
        var precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision) || 2;

        $(element).text(value.toFixed(precision));
    }
    else
    {
        $(element).text(value);
    }
  }
}
```